# How can I use local and remote settings in the same PHP file?

Tags: php

My basic thoughts would be to do something like:

```
$isLocal = // test here

if ($isLocal) {
// local settings here
}
else {
// remote settings here
}
```

I've tried $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] but when I debug in Netbeans, HTTP_HOST does not appear as a parameter.  Basically I'm looking for a robust test for $isLocal

Comment: by local, you mean execute php script on console, or at `http://localhost/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably keep distinct configuration files for each server and exclude them from your revision control system...

```
require_once '/config.local.php';
```

This has the advantage of scaling out to as many development servers as you want, while keeping the live configuration independent and private.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

local address will be different from real

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass a string via the `$_GET` variable? If you were to add `?local=true` to your URLs and then test for this then this would be one way of accomplishing this quite easily. Just remember to disable when it goes live.